# How to disable Microsoft sign in from excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How do I stop this window from appearing in excel when opening using VBA?

I have tried using `DisplayAlerts = False`, but this didn't work

Microsoft Sign in window

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Press Windows key > type "control panel" in.
2. Choose Control Panel > User Accounts and Family Safety > User Accounts.
3. In the left pane, click Manage your credentials.
4. Look for the live account ID and password (Microsoft Account) in the Credential Manager; then, remove it and restart the computer.

Comment: I believe the OP is looking to do this using VBA, not manually.

Comment: @braX Ah sorry then.